# Assigning array values to model in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to take values from an array and assign them to a preexisting model but I don't know how to do that - I've tried looking on here and googling it but I can't find anything that makes sense to me or suits my needs (I will admit that I've probably looked at things that would work, but I don't understand enough to recognize that they would).

This is what I have so far:

```
 string AdditionalData = "Name: John, Age: 43, Location: California";
 string[] firstData = AdditionalData.Split(',');

 foreach (string dataString in firstData)
 {
     string[] temp = dataString.Split(':');
     //Do something here
 }
```

This just splits the string on the commas first then again on the colons, but how do I now get the values (specifically John, 43 and California) to assign them to a preexisting model called Person? Name/Age/Location already exist in the Person model, but they way I am receiving the data is different to my models (which I cannot change) and so I need to split out all the additional data and assign it to the correct model.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated, and apologies if this is a bad question.

Comment: If you have `Person` class, simply do this: `var person = new Person();` then do assignment to its properties like `Person.Name = temp[x];` (`x` = array index number). If the string contains number and model property has `int` type, use either `int.Parse`, `int.TryParse` or `Convert.ToInt32`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto it never occurred to me to do that, thanks, I'll give it a shot! Hopefully it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string AdditionalData = "Name: John, Age: 43, Location: California";
string[] firstData = AdditionalData.Split(',');

Person person = new Person();
person.Name = firstData[0].Split(':')[1].Trim(); //John
person.Age = firstData[1].Split(':')[1].Trim(); //43
person.Location = firstData[2].Split(':')[1].Trim(); //California
```